# Basic queries to a Sqlite database - SQLAlchemy required?

Tags: sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

I did some calculations and stored the results in numerous tables within a sqlite database. Now I want to have those results displayed on a website and therefore introduced myself to flask. 
I already made some first steps and also connected to a sqlite database - and did a plain "print" of a table (`(SELECT * FROM <table>)`) to get a first impression.

What I want to achieve goes beyond a plain query/print of one table. There will be pages where I want to have - say 3 (html)tables. Those three (html)tables come from one sqlite-table.

sqlite-table:

```
product | category | sales 2014 | sales 2015 | sales 2016 
------- | -------- | ---------- | ---------- | ---------- 
p1      | c1       | 23         | 21         | 25
p4      | c4       | 32         | 54         | 123
p3      | c6       | 42         | 34         | 54
...     | ...      | ...        | ...        | ...
```

The tables will be filtered by (for example) "category":

html-table 1

```
product | category | sales 2014 | sales 2015 | sales 2016 
------- | -------- | ---------- | ---------- | ---------- 
p1      | c1       | 23         | 21         | 25
...     | ...      | ...        | ...        | ...
```

html-table 2

```
product | category | sales 2014 | sales 2015 | sales 2016 
------- | -------- | ---------- | ---------- | ---------- 
p4      | c4       | 32         | 54         | 123
...     | ...      | ...        | ...        | ...
```

html-table 3

```
product | category | sales 2014 | sales 2015 | sales 2016 
------- | -------- | ---------- | ---------- | ---------- 
p3      | c6       | 42         | 34         | 54
...     | ...      | ...        | ...        | ...
```

There will be a way to achieve this with a number of SELECT-statements.

The question is if using those RAW-SQL-statements is a good practice?

Generally I'd say no because that is what I read so far. You should use SQLAlchemy. I tried it but I am having a hard time getting my head around it. Furthermore I think it is "to much" (i. e. I do not have relationships between the tables I use, I will not update or alter a table from the website etc.)

What I would like to know from you is if a further look into SQLAlchemy will be of use with regards to what I want to achieve (which is: view the content of some tables on a website)?

Thank you.

Comment: If you can see yourself ever doing another project like this that would involve an SQL database, than I'd say learning to use a little bit of SQLAlchemy would be good.  Even if you won't, it would be a good exercise to try out something new to you and possibly add a new skill to your resume.  However, you don't have to.  As long as you aren't accepting user input that could go into your queries or the DB, then it shouldn't be much of a problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious you haven't tried flask that much, but I will give you a quick intro:

```
class Total(db.Model):
    product = db.Column(db.String())
    category = db.Column(db.String())
    ...

@app.route('/')
def index():
    total = Total.query.all() #get all records
    render_template('index.html', total=total)
#index.html
{% for record in total %}
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>product</th>
              <th>category</th>
             </tr>
          </thead>
        <tr>
            <td>{{record.product}}</td>
            <td>{{record.category}}</td>
         </tr>
    </table>
{% endfor %}
```